# Filezilla skipping files that are not on physical disk from a mapped network drive

Tags: windows-10, ftp, filezilla, mapped-drive

I have a large mapped network drive on my PC and I am recursively uploading its files to an FTP server. The issue I am experiencing is when I select a directory in this drive to upload (recursively), Filezilla will only upload the files that are actually written on the disk (aka it will not fetch the additional files from the network).

HOWEVER, if I drill into one of the subfolders of this directory and manually select all the individual files to upload - Filezilla will correctly process them (and fetch the missing files from the network)

Any ideas on how to get this to work when trying to upload directories recursively? Manually selecting all files is not feasible as they are distributed in many subfolders.